# Read cookie https

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, https

I collect data and use POST request to set cookies on the server in the next way:

```
 HttpCookie cookies = new HttpCookie(name) { 
     Value = value, 
     Expires = DateTime.MaxValue, 
     Secure = true };
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(name);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);
```

After POST request finished I reload page using js.
I use some values from cookie for that page.

I try to get them like:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[NameCookieName] != null)
{
     name = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[NameCookieName].Value;
}
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[RegionCookieName] != null)
{
     region = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[RegionCookieName].Value;
}
```

If I use HTTP it is working fine.

When I use HTTPS cookies set, but when I read them the coookie's value is NULL.

How can I set/get cookie using HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use secure property.
In C# in the HttpCookie class there is a [Secure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure(v=vs.110).aspx) property that allows you to get and set cookies over HTTPS/SSL. I believe you'll need to set up conditions to set and get cookies over those HTTPS pages as well as the HTTP ones.

Cookies set over HTTPS should just work over HTTP so maybe just create a cookie using Secure. Sounds like since this is not set, the cookie is only being set on HTTP pages by default.

You can refer below code:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string authCookie = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

        foreach (string sCookie in Response.Cookies)
        {
            if (sCookie.Equals(authCookie))
            {
                // Set the cookie to be secure. Browsers will send the cookie
                // only to pages requested with https
                var httpCookie = Response.Cookies[sCookie];
                if (httpCookie != null) httpCookie.Secure = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you.